# Salvar arquivo com extensão

Tags: java, mysql, blob

Gostaria de recuperar um arquivo do tipo `blob`, e que fosse acrescentada a extensão, sem que o usuário precise digitar esta extensão na hora de recuperar. Da forma que está, estou salvando e também recuperando, mas recuperando sem a extensão.

Tenho o botão anexar, depois o botão salvar.

Para recuperar o arquivo (salvar na pasta desejada) tenho o botão recuperar.

Botão anexar:

```
private void jBAnexarArquivoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
    caminho = null;
    JFileChooser file = new JFileChooser();
    file.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
    int i = file.showSaveDialog(null);
    if (i == 1) {
        JtextFieldLocalArquivo.setText("");
    } else {
        File arquivo = file.getSelectedFile();
        JtextFieldLocalArquivo.setText(arquivo.getPath());
        caminho = arquivo.getPath();
    }
}
```

Botão Salvar:

```
String path = caminho;
FileInputStream input = null;
File theFile = new File(path);
input = new FileInputStream(theFile);
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(input);
empresa.setAnexo(bytes);
```

Botão recuperar:

```
private void jBRecuperarArquivoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                   
    Connection con = new SQLConnection().getConnection();
    Statement myStmt = null;
    ResultSet myRs = null;
    InputStream input = null;
    FileOutputStream output = null;
    try {
        myStmt = con.createStatement();
        String sql = "select anexo from empresa where idEmpresa = '" + empresaIdField.getText() + "'";
        myRs = myStmt.executeQuery(sql);
        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        int returnValue = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
            String path = selectedFile.getAbsolutePath();

            output = new FileOutputStream(selectedFile);
            if (myRs.next()) {
                input = myRs.getBinaryStream("anexo");
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                while (input.read(buffer) > 0) {
                    output.write(buffer);
                }

            }
        }

    } catch (Exception exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (input != null) {

            try {
                input.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(CondutorInfracaoView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        if (output != null) {
            try {
                output.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(CondutorInfracaoView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        try {
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CondutorInfracaoView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Não entendi muito bem: você está salvando o arquivo em banco, daí quer recuperar a extensão deste arquivo já persistido, é isto?

Comment: Sim, exatamente, tenho o arquivo no banco, e depois o usuário tem a opção de fazer um " download " deste arquivo, porém ele precisa colocar o nome do arquivo  e acrescentar a extensão. E o que eu queria era que ele precisasse apenas informar o nome, e que fosse acrescentada a extensão automaticamente.

Comment: Inclui uma resposta, veja se lhe ajuda :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A abordagem mais simples a ser utilizada, já que você tem o arquivo original, é salvar também a extensão do arquivo ou o *mime type*.

Diferentemente de como você está fazendo, tendo uma coluna do tipo *blob* na tabela `empresa`, talvez uma forma mais organizada seria ter uma relação apenas para os anexos, algo assim:

```sql
CREATE TABLE anexos (
    id int(11) not null,
    content blob not null,
    extension varchar(10) not null,
    empresa_id int(11) not null,
    constraint foreign key (empresa_id) references empresa (id)
)
```

Como pode ver, você persistiria também a informação do tipo do arquivo, então você tem de forma simples a extensão dele, sem se preocupar em tentar adivinhá-lo depois.

Caso você não tenha o arquivo original, apenas os binários, existem algumas abordagens de você recuperar isto, mas não há garantia. Algumas delas são estas (como você está criando um arquivo, estou considerando abordagens que partem de um `File`/`Path`):

- se usa Java >= 7, usar [Files.probeContentType(path)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#probeContentType(java.nio.file.Path)) para recuperar o *mime type* e depois mapear para uma extensão, por exemplo usando o [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/), algo assim:

```java
final File file = new File("F:/Java-8-Features.pdf");
final Path path = file.toPath();
final String mime = Files.probeContentType(path);

// apache tika
final MimeTypes types = MimeTypes.getDefaultMimeTypes();
final MimeType mimeType = types.forName(mime);
final String extension = mimeType.getExtension();
// faça o que for preciso com a extensão
```

- usando [URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream(is)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#guessContentTypeFromStream-java.io.InputStream-)(quase nunca funciona) para recuperar o *mime type* e depois mapear para uma extensão, por exemplo usando também o [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/), mas seria algo assim:

```java
final InputStream is = rs.getBinaryStream("anexo");
final String mime = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream(is);

// apache tika
final MimeTypes types = MimeTypes.getDefaultMimeTypes();
final MimeType mimeType = types.forName(mime);
final String extension = mimeType.getExtension();
// faça o que for preciso com a extensão
```

- fazer sua própria rotina que verifica o cabeçalho do binário. Cada extensão tem seu próprio cabeçalho, então poderia fazer algo que mapeie estes cabeçalhos.

Esta pergunta do SOen tem algumas respostas interessantes também: [Determining binary/text file type in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620993/determining-binary-text-file-type-in-java).

Comment: Seguinte, pensando bem, sua ideia de ter uma tabela apenas para os dados do arquivo seria melhor, até porque no meu caso, seria importante recuperar o arquivo com o mesmo nome que este tinha antes de ser enviado para o banco. Então eu poderia persistir o arquivo, nome e extensão. Correto? Aí só preciso ver como fazer , pois uso um JFileChooser, e desta nova forma, como faria para apenas escolher o local a ser salvo, pois pegaria o nome antigo da tabela arquivo, ou algo assim?

Comment: @Rodrigo salve na tabela apenas o nome do arquivo e extensão, não o diretório todo. Para exibir, você pode recuperar o diretório temporário do usuário e salvar lá. Qualquer coisa poste sua dúvida que tento lhe ajudar

Comment: @ Bruno César Há problemas em salvar o arquivo propriamente dito? Além do espaço em banco ?

Comment: @Rodrigo depende cara, em determinados casos não, mas em outros não é viável, devido a latência por exemplo. Vai muito das necessidades mesmo, no seu caso acredito que não.

Comment: Entendo, vou começar alterar aqui então, com uma nova tabela, com nome, extensão e arquivo. Qualquer coisa posto aqui, obrigado.

Comment: @ Bruno César, adicionei mais trechos de código, Entidade Condutor e a Entidade CondutorInfracao onde faço o lançamento das infrações cometidas pelos condutores. Poderia ajudar a respeito da "nova" Entidade Anexos e como persistir os anexos dessa nova forma?

Comment: @Rodrigo posso sim cara. Cria outra questão com os objetos que tens, explica o cenário de persistência, de preferência incluindo o DDL de suas entidades no banco, daí coloco algumas alternativas para você lá, pode ser?

Comment: Criei outra questão.Obrigado

Comment: @BrunoCésar estou testando em Android, queria saber se funciona para Android v2.3.3 (API level 10)

Comment: Aparentemente, a partir da API 8 boa parte da API Java é suportada. Isso aqui deve ser suportado também, então